# Is it possible to implement a derivative operator in COQ?

Tags: lambda, algebra, coq, calculus, derivative

Is it possible to implement a derivative operator in COQ? That is, an operator that takes an algebraic function such as `x^2` and returns its derivative; in that case, `2x`.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean an operator that would take an arbitrary function, say of type `Z -> Z` and construct its derivative then I believe it's not possible.

Although, you could build your own model of a (certain class) of functions and then you should be able to implement such an operator on that class.

It'd be helpful to know what's your final goal and motivation for that?

Comment: You can probably also use that model to write tactics that simplify propositions about [derivatives](http://coq.inria.fr/stdlib/Coq.Reals.Rderiv.html) by using proof by reflection.